# How to get URL of video or audio from a website with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

i'm using jsoup to parse all the HTML from this website: [news](https://vnexpress.net/ngo-diec-pham-than-tuong-sup-do-4333987.html)

I can fetch all the tilte, description with select some Elements I need. But can't find the video URL element to select. How can i get the video link with jsoup or another kind of library. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood your question, but can't you search for `<video>` elements using JSoup?

All `<video>` elements have a so-called `src` attribute.

Maybe try something like this?

```java
// HTML from your webpage
final var html = "this should hold your HTML";

// Deconstruct into element objects
final var document = Jsoup.parse(html);

// Use CSS to select the first <video> element
final var videoElement = document.select("video").first();

// Grab the video's URL by fetching the "src" attribute
final var src = videoElement.attr("src");
```

Now I did not thoroughly check the website you linked. But some websites insert videos using JavaScript. If this website inserts a video tag after loading, you might be out of luck as Jsoup does not run JavaScript. It only runs on the initial HTML fetched from the page.

Jsoup is an HTML **parser**, which is why it only parses HTML and not, say, generated HTML.